# Docker image build fails due to Kurento-Client dependency

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux, kurento

Trying to build app's docker image using following Dockerfile & Dependencies

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ARG PORT=3000
ENV PORT=$PORT
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apk add --no-cache  nodejs npm
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

```
"dependencies": 
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "kurento-client": "^6.9.0"
```

This results in the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/KurentoForks/reconnect-ws.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Image build works if last dependency is excluded. `NODE v12.18.4`, `NPM 6.14.6` are installed.
App working fine locally . WILL BE GREATLY THANKFUL FOR YOUR HELP.

Comment: you're missing `git` in your image

Comment: @ Anthony to continue build  added RUN apk add git
RUN apk add python3 which eventually ended  into further errors among which are lines gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-118-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/app/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

Comment: @ Anthony Sottile , Thanks. Tried : 'FROM node:carbon' which works but looking to build from an alpine image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after changes to above dockerfile with : ***RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm RUN apk add git RUN apk add python2*** and changing  ***"kurento-client": "^6.15.0"***

kurento-client v6.9.0 complicates things as it needs node v8.17 that has to be  installed via nvm installation  first then git and python added